# Advice on approaching multithreading implementation of list/set operations

Tags: java, multithreading, algorithm, set

I've never made a multithread-capable Java program before and was wondering if I could get some advice on how to approach my task.

**Task Description:** Start with a set of objects (no duplicates) *OBJ*. For each of these objects *n*, remove *n* from *OBJ*, which leaves *OBJ-n*. Then take subsets of size *i* of *OBJ-n*. We'll call the set of all subsets *SUB* and each individual subset *SUB<sub>i</sub>*. Add *n* to each *SUB<sub>i</sub>* to get *SUB<sub>i</sub> + n*. Then remove the object that increases the overall score (arbitrary score metric) of *SUB<sub>i</sub> + n*. If the object that was removed from *SUB<sub>i</sub> + n* is *n*, remove *n* from *OBJ*. Otherwise, continue this for all *n* in *OBJ* with *i =1*. Repeat this for all values of *i* in the range [1, length(*OBJ*)].

**Example:** Start with *OBJ* = {A, B, C, D}. First we remove A and are left with *OBJ-n* = {B, C, D}. We create a set of subsets for *OBJ-n*, which is {{B}, {C}, {D}}. We then add A to each of these *SUB<sub>i</sub>* to get {{A,B}, {A,C}, {A,D}}. We go through each of these *SUB<sub>i</sub> + n* and remove the object that increases the score of *SUB<sub>i</sub> + n*. So we first look at {A,B}. Let's say removing B increases the score. Since *n* is currently A, we do not remove A from *OBJ*. We move to {A,C} and, this time, find that removing A increases the score so we remove A from *OBJ*. We stop scanning through all *SUB<sub>i</sub> + n*, meaning we do not even concern ourselves with {A,D}. We then move to our next value of *n*, which is B (note that A is not in *OBJ* anymore so we do not have to concern ourselves with it when making subsets) and repeat for all *n* in *OBJ*. We repeat this entire process for *i* from 1 to the current length of *OBJ*.

Since I have no multithreading experience, I would appreciate any advice on how to appropriately break this task down into jobs that each thread could execute. I've read about monitors and synchronization of threads but am not too sure how to go about using these resources in my implementation. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you make your requirements crisper? If you just want to increase your exposure to writing correct multithreaded programs in Java, follow a tutorial (on Oracle website, e.g.) first.

Comment: @KedarMhaswade I want my program to run faster using multiple threads as opposed to if it just ran using a single. I've gone through tutorials and can figure out how to implement my program, but I'd like some help in how to approach my problem. For example, multiple threads will be deleting values from _OBJ_. How should I approach this (e.g. synchronization or something)? Should I concurrently perform the task for different values of _i_ or should I concurrently iterate through each _SUBi + n_ for a single _n_? I'd like some advice on how to break up my overall task into subtasks for each thre

Comment: The problem is your question is too open-ended. If you ask more specific question(s), many people here can point you in the right direction. How about starting with a simple producer-consumer, many tasks executing in parallel using executors etc? Your problem perhaps can be modeled as a producer-consumer problem, but then again, it is too broad for a Q+A website.